# What is the time-complexity of this code?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new Input StreamReader(System.in));
    double r, pi=3.14159;
    System.out.println("Please enter radius of sphere:`enter code here` ");
    r = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
    double area=(4/3.0)*pi*(r*r*r);
    System.out.println("Area of sphere is : "+area);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See please: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(1)` as this will always take the same amount of time.

If your input is insanely long, its complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of characters.

Comment: thankx for the help Peter Lawrey

Answer (score 0):

The execution time is not affected by the actual input or the size of the data. Therefore, this snippet has an O(1) complexity.

Comment: ok thankx alot Mureinik.